# Проверка на ноль

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Всем привет, столкнулся с такой вот проблемой, на странице jsp вывожу табличку с данными, хочу сделать что бы после поиска в таблице выводилась надпись "Нет таких данных" если ArrayList size равен нулю, вот пример как я делаю, подскажите как сделать правильно:

```
 <c:forEach items="${vp44150sqlS}" var="vp44150sql" >
                        <tr>
                            <c:if test="${sizeVp44150sqlS == 0}">
                              <th colspan="5" ><c:out value="Здесь ничего" /></th>
                        </c:if>

                        <c:if test="${sizeVp44150sqlS != 0}">
                            <td>
                            <c:out value="${vp44150sql.osdch}" />                                    
                            </td>
                            ...
                            </c:if>                       
                        </tr>   
                    </c:forEach>
```

Немного дополню, на стороне сервлета я узнаю размер `vp44150sqlS` - `int sizeVp44150sqlS = vp44150sqlS.size();` и передаю в `request` -  `request.setAttribute("sizeVp44150sqlS", sizeVp44150sqlS);` И выше пример как на jsp принимаю. Когда ввожу верные значения, все выводится хорошо, когда ввожу значение которого нет в базе, просто шапка таблицы рисуется и все.

Comment: Не обратил сразу внимания на этот момент, а как вы собрались итерировать по int?

Comment: судя по вопросу, я так понимаю, так нельзя делать, да?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в переменной `vp44150sqlS` число. Например 9. Как обойти его в цикле? Никак, числа не являются итерируемыми объектами. Передавайте в контекст шаблона сам ArrayList и проверяйте его в шаблоне

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${not empty vp44150sqlS}">
    <c:forEach items="${vp44150sqlS}" var="vp44150sql">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <c:out value="${vp44150sql.osdch}" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </c:forEach>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <tr>
      <td>Нет данных</td>
    </tr>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: хм, проблема та же, почему то при не верном значении которого нет в базе, эта часть `<c:otherwise>Нет данных</c:otherwise>` не срабатывает, и надписи нет, пустая шапка и все

Comment: Все, я понял, я в начале так и пытался сразу проверять  ArrayList, только проблема в том что я это делал уже в  <c:forEach, и ничего не получалось, да, мне еще учиться и учиться, спасибо большое Вам